# append list values to a dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, append, python-3.6

Python 3.6.0

I am writing a small program that takes user input in the form of:
city, country

I then create a dictionary of key:value pairs where the country
is the key and the cities are the values.

However, I am wanting the value (city) piece to be a list so that a user
can enter in multiple cities for the same country.

Example:

city1, country1
city1, country2
city2, country1

I am close with this code:

```
destinations = {}
while True:
    query = input("Tell me where you went: ")
    if query == '':
        break
    temp = query.split(',')
    if len(temp) != 2:
        temp = []
        continue
    city = [query.split(',')[0]]
    country = query.split(',')[1]
    if country not in destinations:
        destinations[country] = city
    else:
        destinations[country].append(city)
```

My issue is that appended cities are also their own list.  This is from PyCharm:

```
destinations = {' country1': ['city1', ['city2']], ' country2': ['city1']}
```

What I am wanting is this:

```
destinations = {' country1': ['city1', 'city2'], ' country2': ['city1']}
```

I get why this is happening, however, I can't seem to figure out how to append additional cities to the list without each city being in it's own list.

If the user now inputs: city3, country1 then destinations{} should be:

```
destinations = {' country1': ['city1', 'city2', 'city3'], ' country2': ['city1']}
```

You get the idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Just move the list creation - `city = query.split(',')[0]` (or `city, country = query.split(',')`) then `destinations[country] = [city]`. Or use `collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append a list with `[].append([])`, the list itself is appended, and not the actual contents. What you can do is fairly similar to what you currently have, but when you set the variable `city`, set it to the actual text itself and then adjust the code in the `if` statement.

```
destinations = {}
while True:
    query = input("Tell me where you went: ")
    if query == '':
        break
    temp = query.split(',')
    if len(temp) != 2:
        temp = []
        continue
    city = query.split(',')[0] //set city to the string and not the string in a list
    country = query.split(',')[1]
    if country not in destinations:
        destinations[country] = [city] //now the value for the key becomes an array
    else:
        destinations[country].append(city)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the place of the list creation

```
destinations = {}
while True:
    query = input("Tell me where you went: ")
    if query == '':
        break
    temp = query.split(',')
    if len(temp) != 2:
        temp = []
        continue
    city = query.split(',')[0]
    country = query.split(',')[1]
    if country not in destinations:
        destinations[country] = [city]  # <-- Change this line
    else:
        destinations[country].append(city)
```